# Fedora Server Edition: Failed to obtain authentication

Tags: linux, fedora, cockpit

I've just installed new Fedora 27 Server Edition and created admin user.
If I log with this user to cockpit (http://hostname:9090) I am able to connect to Terminal tab and do manual update, however if I try Software Updates or Applications, I see messages:

- Failed to obtain authentication.
- No applications installed or available

Can you please guide me, how to connect this cockpit app with admin account in order to use these features?
Does it have something to do with http://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/authentication.html ?

Comment: How did you create an admin user?

Comment: I created admin during installation. There is a root user and this admin one, with which I am logging to cockpit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. As I get from this address's comments https://fedoramagazine.org/cockpit-overview/, the admin user needs to be in all these user groups in order to fully work with cockpit:

- systemd-journal
- adm
- wheel

Alternatively the root account can be used to perform system administrative tasks, such as update or install.

Comment: This helped on a standard Debian Server installation with sudo users that could login to cockpit but couldn't perform system updates or make any system changes. Thx